# Using Stopwatch timer versus DateTime comparisons every 1 second?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, .net-core, stopwatch

Imagine we have a dedicated OS thread, that must do something every 4.30 minutes.

You cannot suspend the thread, because it needs to check/do other things, nor can you use await/async, because that would cause the command to drop out of the dedicated OS thread, defeating the purpose of first creating one.

To solve the problem above, I found 2 solutions:

- Use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to start a new `Stopwatch` object, and compare it every 1 second if it reached the desired time-frame: `if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds == 258000) { ...}`
- Use `System.DateTime` to initialize a `DateTime` object `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(4.30)` and compare that to the current date every 1 second: `if (DateTime.UtcNow >= initializedDate) { ... }`

First approach uses a `Stopwatch`. I think the Stopwatch uses a thread to do all the work, which is why I wanted to avoid it?

The second approach uses a lot of `DateTime` objects. Every 1 second we'd be constructing a new `DateTime` object of the current date.

Comment: It depends on the accuracy you need on the 4.30 minutes. Polling is less accurate than a timer event.

Comment: @jdweng No accuracy is needed, unless the target is off by half a minute.

Comment: You can have the thread wait on a blocking queue and post an item via timer every 4.5 mins ... ? Just an idea. Or set an AutoresetEvent ...

Comment: @Fildor that's a nice idea, but the `System.Threading.Timer` uses a ThreadPool thread, which I'd hate to involve. The reason I'm already using a dedicated thread is to avoid using a Thread pool one.

Comment: Maybe the `DispatcherTimer`? I haven't looked at it in a long time, but I thought it ran on the same thread. Then you can use the Elapse event and interval to have a clean bit of code that runs every 4,5 minutes.

Comment: _" is to avoid going to the Thread pool"_ what's wrong about that?

Comment: `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4.5)).ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(x => { /* Do stuff here */});`

Comment: @Fildor Launch a bunch of timers and risk starving the thread pool.

Comment: @SpiritBob is there any reason why you do not want to use a ThreadPool Thread

Comment: How many would that be if the only thing they do is set some flag? I consider that really premature optimization. With that argument you could question the pool's existence on the whole. You could question the existence of software on the whole, because you _could_ use up memory or CPU ... but you don't, do you?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've never used `System.Reactive.Observable` before. What are the noticeable differences to the code you posted versus a normal `System.Threading.Timer` approach?

Comment: @SpiritBob - The reactive framework provides a LINQ interface to use event-based programming. It tends to make a lot of code fit into a few simple operations, making the code easier to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two solutions are equivalent unless you want very high precision: `Stopwatch` will use a high precision system timer if available and falls back to `DateTime` if not. To address your concerns:

1. `Stopwatch` does NOT use a separate thread. It just reads the system ticks (high or low precision) and does some math for you.
2. `DateTime` is a struct so creating a new instance every second should be cheap and put zero pressure on the GC.

I'd use the `Stopwatch` because it gives me the elapsed time for free. :)

Comment: It would be worth noting that using either `Stopwatch` and `DateTime` would tie up a thread and thus be inefficient. Using a timer allows the code to co-opt the operating system and thus is much more efficient.

Comment: @Enigmativity how would you avoid their use then, without delegating the work to other threads, such as Thread pool threads? We're doing all of this from a dedicated thread.

Comment: @SpiritBob - What's wrong with using another thread to push things on to the current thread. The Windows Forms message pump works that way when you call `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: @Enigmativity nothing's wrong, unless in the case where you've intentionally created a dedicated thread to do some work. Ideally, it should not delegate it's work to other threads - it defeats the purpose of having a dedicated thread in that sense. You're better off awaiting a task in that case.

Comment: @SpiritBob - I'm suggesting to intentionally create a thread to schedule work on the original dedicated thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity why use a dedicated thread then - we can just switch back and forth between Thread Pool threads using the TPL?

Comment: @SpiritBob - I thought that's what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @Enigmativity exactly. How am I avoiding it if I do what you suggest?

Comment: In .net core DateTime using high precision: GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime